# Are there any systems that use a continuous initiative order?

Tags: initiative

Essentially, I am wondering if there are any tabletop-roleplaying games in which players are always playing in turns. I am curious about how it impacts the game tempo, the participation of the players, and the timing of encounters.

Any example systems and brief descriptions of those systems would be much appreciated!

In most tabletop roleplaying games I have played, players can interact with the world around them at-will and can explore the next room, ask a question of an NPC, or try to climb a high wall whenever they want to.

I am wondering if there are any TTRPGs where the players are interacting with the fictional world in a defined mechanical order, even outside of combat or "social combat".

As a follow-up, what impacts do these mechanics have on the example game systems?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "players are always playing in turns" - if I don't quite understand what you mean, I suspect others might not either.

Comment: Do you mean it remains RAW turn-based, even outside of combat (etc.)?

Comment: @Jason_c_o yes, it remains RAW turn-based even outside combat etc.

Comment: Context from the FAQ: [Are Game Recommendation Questions On Topic, Revisited](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5747/52137) Specifically this seems to fall under "Are there any games that let me do (thing) / have this specific mechanic?"

Comment: Would you be opposed to this being edited into asking "what is this called?" That way you either have a term to search on, or if it's a small list a set games that use those terms...?